# Dúvida sobre gravar um dado e atualizar uma div logo em seguida

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Bom dia pessoal.
Apenas com jQuery e Ajax eu consigo inserir um dados no banco e logo em seguida atualizar uma div na página ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual seu banco de dados? O que usa no backend? quer inserir diretamente ou enviar uma solicitação pro backend e a partir dele salvar o dado?

Comment: Estou usando mysql e java. A intenção é da pessoa postar alguma dúvida e quando clicar no botão postar ele grava no banco de dados e em seguida atualiza a div com as postagens.

Answer (score 0):

Consegue, sempre que você fizer uma requisição ajax voce terá uma função de callback, que será executada quando a requisição terminar e retornar algo, no caso do ajax seria algo assim:
`$.ajax({
url: 'url.do.serviço',
type: POST // metodo http a ser usado na requisição,
data: {algo_a_ser_enviado: dado_a_ser_salvo},
success: function(data){
// função de callback
}`

na função de callback você pode acessar a div por meio de um id ou classe:
`$("#idDaDiv").html("oque colocar no conteúdo da div");`
lembrando que usa-se "#" no caso de pegar o elemento pelo id e "." no caso de pegar pela classe. Espero ter sido claro.

Dica: leia sempre a documentação -> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/